# Porting a command-line Unix app to Windows

Tags: windows, unix, command-line-interface, porting

I have a command-line utility without GUI on Unix that I plan to distribute to Windows users. Unfortunately, it's been well over a decade since I touched a Windows box, so I am wondering if there are any traps I should be wary of. I am distributing this to non-programmers on Windows.

Specifically:

- Can Windows users handle command-line options?
- What instructions do I use to tell the Windows users
     to install and run a command-line app?

Comment: Do you think your UNIX utility would work on Windows? I highly doubt it! How have you coded your utility?

Comment: This is a highly subjective question.  What type of users are you targeting?  What does your app do?  What type of low-level calls does it make?  What toolchain under windows do you plan on using?